# how efficiently modify 5000 pixels of big UIImage 60 times per second with Swift

Tags: swift, performance, uiimageview, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I've got a UIImageView with its image myImage (= big UIImage 2000x2000)

I want to modify this image 60 times per second for about 5000 new different pixels each time (they can be everywhere in the image, but are usually in the same area of the image each time)

Currently, I use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext 60 times per second to draw and save the new image with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext (see code below).

Is there a more efficient way to do that ?

```
var newpixels = [Smartpoint]()
... Fill newpixels with new pixels...

DispatchQueue.global().async
{
    self.myImage = self.drawOnImage(image :self.myImage, points: newpixels)                   
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        self.myImageView.image = self.myImage
    }
}

...

func drawOnImage(image: UIImage, points : [Smartpoint]) -> UIImage? {

        autoreleasepool {

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
     
            // Draw the starting image in the current context as background
            image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
            
            // Get the current context
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

            context.setBlendMode(.normal)

            for point in points
            {
                ... make something with the point ...
            }
            
            
            context.drawPath(using: .stroke) 
            
            // Save the context as a new UIImage
            let myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            
            // Return modified image
            return myImage
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like Metal and Accelerate would be needed here.